# How to Convert/rendered Blueprint doc to API

Tags: apiblueprint

Is there any good tool available for rendering the blueprint document and showing in the API format? I even tried the `Drafer` ,`Sublime Text Editor` but no luck(very less/poor documents are available to setup tool).Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean how to render an APIBlueprint to an HTML document, you should definitely have a look to [aglio](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio).

Or, you can always use Apiary.io itself to host and render your documentation.

Does that clarify your issue?